# Questions on a manual implementation of Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm (trying) to implement Enhanced Analytics on an aspx/mvc website.

First, I set up a UA Tag triggering off the custom event "checkout":
Tag Type: Universal Analytics
Track Type: Event
Event Action: Checkout
Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true
Use Data Layer: true

Then, I created a Custom HTML tag to push the checkout event to the Data Layer; firing off of Window Load of the checkout URL.  the custom HTML is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'checkout',
        'ecommerce': {
            'checkout': {
                'actionField': { 'step': '1' },
                'products': [{
                    'name': 'product1',
                    'id': '123456',
                    'price': '500',
                    'dimension2': 'Acccepted',
                    'dimension5': '12345'
                }]
            }
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

GTM preview shows the custom html tag firing but the associated UA Event tag does not fire.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small mistake in your JS. You forgot to call defined function (pay attention at `()` at the end):

```
(function() {
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'checkout',
        'ecommerce': {
            'checkout': {
                'actionField': { 'step': '1' },
                'products': [{
                    'name': 'product1',
                    'id': '123456',
                    'price': '500',
                    'dimension2': 'Acccepted',
                    'dimension5': '12345'
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}())
```

Comment: Thanks you, tiny oversight but its been killing me!